# What happens if you call glBufferData on a mapped buffer?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

What happens if you call glBufferData on a buffer currently mapped with glMapBufferRange? I suggest it would be illegal, but I cannot find anything in the spec:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBufferData.xhtml

It is illegal in glDrawArrays spec.

Ok, additional challenge:

What if we have context resource sharing and the buffer is currently mapped in thread A with context A, then thread B on context B calls glBufferData on it?

Answer (score 0):

For a single context scenario when `glBufferData()` is called then the existing buffer object is deleted, any active bindings of that resource in that context will be unbound, and any active mappings will be removed. If you call `glUnmapBuffer()` after `glBufferData()` from within the same context then you'll get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error, because the state of the new version of the buffer is not initially mapped.

For a multi-context scenario it gets more complicated. OpenGL ES defines a weakly coherent state management model (to avoid expensive locking requirements on performance critical call paths).

- Render state that belongs to the context (e.g. binding information, enable bits) is never modifiable by another context (can be implemented lockless).
- Resource state that belongs to an object (e.g. buffers, samplers, textures) is weakly coherent. A context will see its own changes immediately, but only pick up changes written by another context when it binds the resource (only needs locking on bind changes).
- Resource data payload is not coherent at all. If you want to ensure that data is available from one context in another then you must include manual synchronization between the threads.

Thread A calling `glMapBuffer()` will create a copy of the master state of Buffer "version 1", including a local state setting that the buffer is "mapped".

Thread B calling `glBufferData()` will create a new version of the buffer resource "version 2", but this will not impact the state held by Thread A which will continue to reflect the state at the time that the buffer was bound in thread A (version 1).

Thread A calling `glUnmapBuffer()` will work fine, because it will unmap buffer "version 1" (the mapped state is local to the Thread A context, and that still says the buffer is "mapped").

Note that the data contents of the buffer that Thread A sees after Thread B calls `glBufferData()` is unpredictable (it could be the old data, it could be the new data), in accordance with the design that data is not coherent at all. If there were no pending draw operations then it is valid for the driver to simply reuse the memory that "version 1" of the buffer was backed by to contain the content that was uploaded for "version 2". If you want guarantees about data consistency across contexts then you need manual synchronization (it's conceptually just like having two threads call `glBufferData()` on the same buffer at the same time).

I'd recommend reading Chapter 5 of the OpenGL ES 3.2 spec.

Comment: Ok, so let's say thread A calls glMapBufferRange assuming that the mapped area has a certain size. Then thread B calls glBufferData, but with a smaller size than before. Can this mean that the mapping pointer from thread A now points to an area smaller than requested, resulting in a segfault at access?

Comment: No, the pages should be ref-counted by the mapping operation.

Comment: ... but if you end up with this situation you are already into undefined behavior, so it won't crash, but it might render garbage ..

Comment: When exactly did we go into undefined behaviour? Does one of the functions throw an error code?

Comment: "Note that the data contents of the buffer that Thread A sees after Thread B calls glBufferData() is unpredictable (it could be the old data, it could be the new data), in accordance with the design that data is not coherent at all"

Comment: It's not going to crash, but the content of the memory at that point in time is no longer well defined in the absence of additional synchronization. This isn't specific to mapbuffer - any concurrent update to the same memory (e.g. two colliding concurrent updates using `glBufferSubData()`) would have the same problem). Not crashing is the least of your problems if you have a design that may attempt to concurrently update the same memory from two threads without synchronization ...